# AngularJS array of objects ng-show or ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to show a message of "No categories" so im using this:

```
<div ng-repeat="categoryItem in categories">
                 <div ng-show="categoryItem.length">No categories</div>
```

And doesn't work.

It's an array of objects, so in the console if i have 2 categories i can see this:

```
Array[2]
0
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:77"
created_at
:
"2016-12-07T19:45:29.997063"
created_by
:
"test"
id
:
39
name
:
"Category 1"
updated_at
:
"2016-12-07T19:45:29.997105"
updated_by
:
null
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:78"
created_at
:
"2016-12-07T19:45:34.202915"
created_by
:
"test"
id
:
40
name
:
"Category 2"
updated_at
:
"2016-12-07T19:45:34.202947"
updated_by
:
null
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
2
```

So, when i delete all the categories i programmed a simple if:

```
                if($scope.categories.length === 0){
                console.log("No categories");
            }
```

It works but the message are not showed in the view, what im doing wrong?

Comment: wouldn't you want to show the data when there isn't a length, rather than when there is?

Comment: I try !categoryItem.length and categoryItem.length === 0 and doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message will not display when there are 0 categories because the message is inside your `ng-repeat`. Because the length of the categories array is 0 there will be 0 items in the view.

Place your "*No Categories*" message outside the `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="categoryItem in categories">
    <div>{{categoryItem.name}}</div>
</div>
<div ng-hide="categories.length > 0">No categories</div>
```

Please note that I'm using `ng-hide` and checking the length of your `categories` array to determine if the "*No categories*" message should be displayed.

Comment: You have all the reason, that's the correct solution. It works, thank you.

Comment: If this solution worked for you please feel free to accept this answer as correct.